# Dart Fold vs Reduce

Tags: dart

What's the difference between **fold** and **reduce** in Dart and when would I use one as opposed to the other? They seem to do the same thing according to the docs.

> Reduces a collection to a single value by iteratively combining each
>   element of the collection with an existing value using the provided
>   function.

Comment: Actually the docs are slightly different for both functions.

Fold: Reduces a collection to a single value by iteratively combining each element of the collection with an existing value using the provided function.

Reduce: Reduces a collection to a single value by iteratively combining elements of the collection using the provided function.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

[reduce](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) can only be used on non-empty collections with functions that returns the same type as the types contained in the collection.

[fold](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html) can be used in all cases.

For instance you cannot compute the sum of the length of all strings in a list with `reduce`. You have to use `fold` :

```dart
final list = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc'];
// compute the sum of all length
list.fold(0, (t, e) => t + e.length); // result is 6
```

By the way `list.reduce(f)` can be seen as a shortcut for `list.skip(1).fold(list.first, f)`.

Comment: I think your example of what you can't do isn't right, as print([1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => "$a$b"))  => "123". But that's because "1".toString() => "1".

Comment: Exact, my example was almost right. I have updated my answer with `<int>[1,2,3]`. With `print(<int>[1,2,3].reduce((a, b) => "$a$b"))` you get the exception: _type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'function result'_ at runtime in checked mode and the analyzer warns: _The argument type '(dynamic, dynamic) -> String' cannot be assigned to the parameter type '(int, int) -> int'_.
Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It still might be better to pick an example that can't be "fixed" by just removing the types or running unchecked.

Comment: The GPT chatbot didn't know about the "same type in reduce"-thing - SO still worth checking out from time to time ;)

Comment: print(strings.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => (previousValue as int)+element.length));
  print(strings.reduce((value, element) => (value.length + element.length).toString()));

Answer (score 8):

There are a few noticeable differences between them. Other than the ones mentioned above, it is worth highlighting that `fold()` is able to operate on collections that are empty without producing an error.

`reduce()` will throw an error saying `Bad state: No element` whereas `fold()` will return a non-null value back, using the initial value passed onto it as a fallback return value.

I've discussed about this at length here:

https://medium.com/@darsshanNair/demystifying-fold-in-dart-faacb3bd4efd